# Javascript back button not working properly -scrolling to the bottom of the page, instead of previous scroll location

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm using the following code on a wordpress website and it is only present on the post pages:

```
<button onclick="history.back()">Back</button>
```

What I would like the code to do is bring the user directly back to the spot where they left off on the previous page and for the most part the code is working fine.

**Problem:** After clicking forward and then clicking back a few times - the back button will continue to bring you back button, however not to the same scroll spot - it actually brings you back to the bottom of the webpage and will keep doing this every time until you leave the website and then return.

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my website address - if that helps >> http://rumpleskilton.com/djs-bands-singers/

(to see the problem - select one of the listings and then click the back button, which is just above the page header. It could take several times to see the problem. Just click a few of the listings.)

Answer (score 0):

have you try this way ?

`<button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>`

i hope it's help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response - egin10. Yeah, I've used that code too, but still having the same problem.

Comment: are you want to back to previous link ? with `history.back()`

Comment: have you try this way ? `onclick="window.history.go(-1)"` to previous or back to 1 page

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Chrome. Chrome is known to demonstrate such behaviour. Try with Firefox and MS Edge and see if you get the same result (I trust you won't).

In any case, the safest method is to use the page URL to navigate to, instead of `back()`. Alternatively, you could save the last page name in the url (?lastpage=index or whatever) and change your `back()` function to grab that page name and navigate there.

Trusting the browser behaviour is not your friend in this situation.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's only happening on chrome. I just don't want visitors using chrome, that don't know about the back button at the top of the browser, to experience the problem. 

- (?lastpage=index or whatever) Would this be part of the javascript code?

Comment: Aydin. Do you know how I can send the user back to the top of previous page using a js code. 

- I think the top of the page would be better than the bottom.

Comment: You can add this to your homepage, so that it will scroll to top every time it is loaded:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
</script>`